# How to set SELinux to allow CGI script to create a file

Tags: httpd, selinux

I'm writing a CGI for httpd on CentOS 7, which create and write files on a directory under home.
When I enable SELinux, it causes Internal Server Error. How can I setup SELinux?

The command `sudo ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC -ts recent` shows an error below.

```
time->Fri Sep 24 09:03:23 2021
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1632441803.684:10739412): proctitle=2F7573722F62696E2F707974686F6E330075706C6F61642E636769
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1632441803.684:10739412): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f69aa9978c0 a1=a00c2 a2=180 a3=3 items=0 ppid=12020 pid=5135 auid=4294967295 uid=1018 gid=1018 euid=1018 suid=1018 fsuid=1018 egid=1018 sgid=1018 fsgid=1018 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="upload.cgi" exe="/usr/bin/python3.6" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_user_script_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1632441803.684:10739412): avc:  denied  { add_name } for  pid=5135 comm="upload.cgi" name="16r3sq_k" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_user_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_script_exec_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

The context of the directory is set as below.

```
$ ls -ldZ uploaded
drwxrwxr-x. user user unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_rw_content_t:s0 uploaded
```

Comment: Your program `upload.cgi` is trying to create a file named `16r3sq_k` in some directory. The logs don't say which directory. What directory is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The directory is `~/public_html/uploaded/`. I set `httpd_user_rw_content_t` for the directory but I'm not sure this is the right context settings.

Comment: SELinux is very insistent that a web server or processes it spawns cannot write to user home directories (only read is permitted). Place your web site in an appropriate place in the filesystem which SELinux recognizes, e.g. `/srv/www/myappname`.